# como retornar a ultima data em timestamp fazendo o group by de um mesmo id no mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou com um problema tenho um tabela que tem a coluna serial, equipamento e um data timestamp não tem chave primaria pois essa tabela seria um histórico, eu na tabela tenho varias linhas com o mesmo serial porém preciso trazer da ultima data só que preciso trazer em um linha só, mas quando coloco o `group by serial order by timestamp desc` ele não trás a ultima data inserida como que eu faria isso segue a query abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM spare_change.cad_checklist group by serial order by timestamp desc ;
```

O retorno seria

```
serial | equipamento |         data 
  60   |    item     | 2010-04-05 10:30:58
```

A ultima data seria por exemplo a seguinte
2010-04-06 09:59:10

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) para obter a maior data e agrupar pela demais:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0b0a2/7)

```
SELECT 
  serial
  , equipamento
  , max(data) AS DataMaisRecente
FROM 
  cad_checklist 
GROUP BY 
  serial
  , equipamento
ORDER BY 
  DataMaisRecente DESC;
```

Comment: eu havia feito isso trás a ulitma data, mais as informações não esta referente ao cadastro do timestamp

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "não esta referente ao cadastro do timestamp" poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Provavel que isso funcione pra ti.

```
SELECT serial, max(data )
  FROM spare_change.cad_checklist 
 GROUP BY serial;
```

Assim não precisaria do order by, por que só retornaria uma unica linha

Comment: Se houver mais de um equipamento e estes possuam número de serial diferente, consequentemente terá mais de uma linha. Nesse caso o `order by` é opcional.

Comment: Entendi que ele precisa de uma linha por serial, então não importaria a ordem das datas para seriais diferentes (só depende da regra de negocio neste caso). Mas sim, está correto neste ponto de vista.

Comment: Sim, é que pela sua resposta deu a entender que a query retornaria uma única linha, faltou só especificar que é uma linha por serial